# creating a button function BEFORE selected items on gui

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface

Im creating a form and something dont seems to work here. at the beginning of the script i declaring $button1_click as so:

```
#Link Button
$Button1_Click = {
Write-Host "link button"
$listBox.SelectedItems
$listBox2.SelectedItem}
```

i then continute to build to gui with 2 item lists

```
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,430)
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$button1.Text = 'Link'
$Button1.Add_Click($Button1_Click)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.Height = 350
$listbox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

$listBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,40)
$listBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,20)
$listBox2.Height = 350
```

but when i hit button 1 i dont seem to have anything in the $listbox variable, maybe it got something to do it was declared before that other piece of code?

Comment: This should be more of a scope-problem. The variables `$listbox1` and `$listbox2` don't exist in the scriptblock of `Button1_Click`. You can either parse the variables to the script block or use another scope like `$script:listbox1`.

Comment: `SelectedItem` and `SelectedItems` are used in differnt ways, especially when retrieving text values - look at `$listbox.SelectedItems.Text`. Also you'll find it a lot easier if you code in this order: Create form elements first, then add them to the form, then code the actions for those elements like button presses, item selection etc.

Comment: Well problem is, if i code actions of the buttons after i already made it and showd it, the click code wont run

Comment: Write-Host does to write to a GUI, it writes to the console. Your code should only be using the form elements. Write-Host should be generally avoided, except in specific formatting use cases and when you are outputting screen colorized text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer you accepted in another post you submitted about GUI and PowerShell with List boxes (which seems to be just a longer one of this one.):

[Im having promlen with button functions in gui powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802960/im-having-promlen-with-button-functions-in-gui-powershell)

And this one as well.

[Powershell output in color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804287/powershell-output-in-color/61809138#61809138)