# Im having promlen with button functions in gui powershell

Tags: powershell, scope

I am struggling here. i cannot figure out how to make the button functions read the $listbox1.selectedItems and $listbox2.selectedItem
whats wrong here?
if i try to look at the $listbox items after the OK button been pressed it will show me but not if i call the function button, ive deleted some unneccesery code parts.

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Text = 'Link'

$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Text = 'UnLink'

$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3.Text = 'ShowGPOlink'

$button4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button4.Text = 'ShowOUlink'

#OK Button
$button5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button5.Text = 'Done'
$button5.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listbox1.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

$listBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

[void] $listBox1.Items.addRange($GPOLIST)
[void] $listBox2.Items.Addrange($OUHOLDER.CanonicalName)

$form.Controls.Add(...)
$form.AcceptButton = $button5

$button1.Add_Click({ LinkFn })
$button2.Add_Click({ UnLinkFn })
$button3.Add_Click({ ShowGPO })
$button4.Add_Click({ ShowOU })

function LinkFn {
#for some reason it returns nothing
$listBox1.selecteditems
$listbox2.SelectedItem 
Write-Host "function link"
}
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){ 
$listBox1.selecteditems
$listbox2.SelectedItem  }
```

Comment: Write-Host should be avoided, as its only purpose is to dump text to the console, colorized or not. Well, there are a few formatting instances where it's useful, but what you re doing is not one of them. Output to the console is the Powershell default unless you tell it to do otherwise. If you must use Write, use Write-Output or look at Out-Host and Tee-Object as well. Also, the sample code you posted will not work anyway as is, forcing us to have to change it the make it work/display with lists and thus assist. This [$form.Controls.Add(...)] is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not leveraging the provided PowerShell docs examples and tweaking as needed:

> [Selecting Items from a List Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/selecting-items-from-a-list-box?view=powershell-7)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please select a computer:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.Height = 80

[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-001')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-002')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-003')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-004')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-005')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-006')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('atl-dc-007')

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $x
}
```

If you have the Multiselect defined, then change the block to this...

```
$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'  


if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    ForEach ($ListItem in $listBox.SelectedItems)
    {$ListItem}
}
```

So, as I said, this required me to physically re-write what you have here to explain and show you what you would be looking at. This will show the formatted GUI, with a prepopulated list, that when you single or multi-select and item from listbox1, and click the Link button, which fires the function LinkFn, it will copy that selection to Listbox2 and will not close the form.

The below code is not doing anything differently than what is shown in the PS help other than sending the results to another GUI element, and not closing the form via the default OK return. All of which is a common thing in GUI design.

```
#region Begin environment initialization

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#endregion Begin environment initialization


#region Begin functions and code behind

function DoneFn { }
function ShowModuleFn { }
function ShowProcessFn { }
function UnLinkFn { }
function LinkFn 
{ 
    $listBox1.selecteditems
    # $listbox2.SelectedItems
    [void] $listBox2.Items.Addrange($listBox1.selecteditems)
}

$List1 = (Get-Process).Name
# $List2 = (Get-Module).Name

#endregion End functions and code behind


#region Begin  GUI code
$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '634,339'
$Form.text                       = 'Form'
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$ListBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox1.text                   = 'listBox1'
$listBox1.SelectionMode          = 'MultiExtended'
$ListBox1.width                  = 269
$ListBox1.height                 = 176
$ListBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,21)

$ListBox2                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox2.text                   = 'listBox2'
$listBox2.SelectionMode          = 'MultiExtended'
$ListBox2.width                  = 300
$ListBox2.height                 = 175
$ListBox2.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(318,21)

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = 'Link'
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,238)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.text                    = 'Unlink'
$Button2.width                   = 60
$Button2.height                  = 30
$Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(127,241)
$Button2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button3                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button3.text                    = 'ShowProcess'
$Button3.width                   = 88
$Button3.height                  = 30
$Button3.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,297)
$Button3.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button4                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button4.text                    = 'ShowModules'
$Button4.width                   = 105
$Button4.height                  = 30
$Button4.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(127,297)
$Button4.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button5                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button5.text                    = 'Done'
$Button5.width                   = 60
$Button5.height                  = 30
$Button5.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(556,298)
$Button5.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@(
    $ListBox1,
    $ListBox2,
    $Button1,
    $Button2,
    $Button3,
    $Button4,
    $Button5
))

$Button1.Add_Click({ LinkFn })
$Button2.Add_Click({ UnLinkFn })
$Button3.Add_Click({ ShowProcessFn })
$Button4.Add_Click({ ShowModuleFn })
$Button5.Add_Click({ DondFn })

[void] $listBox1.Items.addRange($List1)
# [void] $listBox2.Items.Addrange($List2)

#endregion End GUI code

# Call the GUI
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: because in the given example there it only ok button which works different from other buttons, beside i dont want the script to end (that happens after you press ok). and using this example i still get the error, you can try adding button and see

Comment: If you mean the PS help example, this works as posted. So, relative to this --- [using this example i still get the error] -- are you talking your example or the PS Help example or your example? The number of buttons and the code behind that button would not matter since you would/should be binding only one function per instantiated button.

Comment: As for not exiting the GUI, then again, why are you using Write-Host at all? Are you saying you want to write the selection from L1 to L2? If not and you are not showing via the console, then you need another GUI element to write to. So, just adding one button, to check out what you are after, is not a thing. I'd have to change your code posted to add all the UI elements, change their positions, etc. Hence my request for you to add a more. As written your list boxes would be on top of each other, same for the buttons. The PS help sample can easily be tweaked for what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all, THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME AND EFFORT!, i actually am using the write-host just to debug and to understand what is the problem with the code. my final goal here are som GPO in the left pane and some OU in the right pane, and giving the user the ability to choose multiple GPO and one ou from the right, and link or unlink them. you have helped me so much! thank you again for your time!