# Powershell output in color

Tags: powershell

I am using a Powershell form to output some data and I am wondering how I can get the output in color?

I am not using write-host. That is not what I am looking for. I know you can use -ForegroundColor for that.

It's for `Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like 'Username'" | Select Enabled`

If output is False it needs to be in Red. If output is true just regular color.

Anyone who can help me?

Many thanks.
Ralph.

Comment: Color is part of the user interface.  Objects, like the ones being output by your command, don't have colors, otherwise.  Why do you say `Write-Host` "is not what I am looking for"?  If you want to customize the object display with colors then `Write-Host` is the way to do it.

Comment: It's because I need to use it in a Powershell Form. Then I can't use Write-Host...

Comment: what type of form is it? xaml or the older one?

Comment: I see.  I missed the word "form" in the question.  Presumably you mean PowerShell instantiating WinForms controls?  It'd be helpful to show the code of this form and how it loads the data from that command.

Comment: @Ralph can you post the code for the form component that's supposed to show the colored output?

Comment: You set the color in the form control properties via a control event. You run your code, check for the results, update the control with the results then modify the control text color view.

Answer (score 2):

A follow-up to my comment

```
#region Begin functions and code behind

function RunCode { 
    $ProcessList = (Get-Process).Name
    If ($ProcessList -ge 10)
    {$DataSet.ForeColor = 'red'}
    else {$DataSet.ForeColor = 'black'}
    [void] $DataSet.Items.Addrange($ProcessList)
}

#endregion End functions and code behind


#region Begin GUI code
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '511,501'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$RunCode                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$RunCode.text                    = "RunCode"
$RunCode.width                   = 90
$RunCode.height                  = 30
$RunCode.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(19,17)
$RunCode.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$DataSet                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$DataSet.text                    = "listBox"
$DataSet.width                   = 204
$DataSet.height                  = 144
$DataSet.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,98)

$Form.controls.AddRange(@(
    $RunCode,
    $DataSet
))

$RunCode.Add_Click({ RunCode })

#endregion Begin GUI code


# Call the GUI
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```